# Convert a Robotium Project in Maven Project.

Tags: android, maven, junit, robotium

I've a Robotium project that works fine. I can run tests launching application as "Android Junit Test".

Then I Mavenized projeck clicking on Convert to Maven Project and I get this error in console:

```
R.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version!
```

Then I try to run again the project as "Android Junit Test" but I get this error in console:

```
Test run failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.RuntimeException'
```

I tryed to

- run Project -> Clean but I've the same problem
- I restarted eclipse and it gives me a lots of error; I can solve them clicking on advice: "ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 cannot be resolved to a type" and clicking on Fixing project Setup that adds Android.jar for me but it keeps on give me the same error.

Other strange thing is that if I click on:
Run -> Mvn compile exec:java maven execution

I get this:

```
ERROR: M2_HOME is set to an invalid directory.
M2_HOME = "null"
Please set the M2_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of the Maven installation

"cmd" non Š riconosciuto come comando interno o esterno,
 un programma eseguibile o un file batch.
```